# How to display ascending numbers and descending beside it using for loop in c

Tags: c

I've been into this problem lately, and I just ca't figure out how. I wan't an output to be like this:

```
Enter Number: 5

1      5
2      4
3      3
4      2
5      1
```

And here's my code:

```
int c;
int n;
int i;
printf("Enter Number Count Limit: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for (c=1;c<=n;c++)
{
    for (i=c;i<0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d\t%d",c,i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

Can Anyone please tell me whats wrong with my code. It has no errors and it has an empty output. Thank You!

Comment: Ask yourself what happens on the first iteration of the inner loop.  Notice that you have `i<0` as your test condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not thing there's a reason to use 2 for loops. I would go with something like this:

```
for (c=0; c<n; c++){
         printf("%d\t%d\n", c+1, x-c);
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It is also the right one. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is problem in the 2nd loop condition.

```
for (i=c;i<0;i--)
```

Here `i` will start with `c` which is from 1 to n and you wrote the condition `i<0` but `i` will always be at least 1. So this loop will not execute. For this `printf("%d\t%d",c,i);` will not be reached. You will just get executed `printf("\n")` for `n` times.

This will do:

```
int c;
int n;
int i;
printf("Enter Number Count Limit: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for (c=1;c<=n;c++)
{
    printf("%d\t%d\n",c,n-c+1);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Wow! I don't think it would be that easy. My mind is just getting it more complicating. I never thought that it would take just 1 loop. Thanks man. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
for (i=c;i<0;i--)
```

try this:

```
for (i=n;i>0;i--)
```

Comment: Nope. It outputs too many numbers. A single loop could do. But thanks! Appreciate your help. @TheodoraSchier